# How to create folder & save app related files (jpg) as per Scoped Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-11, scoped-storage

Just like Whatsapp, Telegram does, I want to create a folder "DemoApp" and save .jpg images inside it in Internal storage `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` of **Android 11 as per scoped storage**.

I have already given following permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />

And also written code to grant Read/Write Permission of folders from user.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "LOG, Permission to record denied");

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
```

But still after user grants folder permissions, the folder is been created, but the Images are not being saved in the 'DemoApp' folder.

**Following is the code which is working till Android 10 but not in Android 11:**

```
File localFile;

final String folderLocation= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "DemoApp" + "/";

        //  userImage.setImageDrawable(postOwnerImage.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.profilepic));
        
        localFile = new File(folderLocation);
      
            localFile.mkdirs();

            final File file = new File(folderLocation+ "/" + "Picture1" + ".jpg");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Picasso.get().load(file).resize(1024, 800).noPlaceholder().onlyScaleDown().into(postOwnerImage);
                } else {
                    StorageReference storageReference;
                    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

                    String STORAGE_PATH_DOWNLOADS = "ImageFolder" + "/";   // backslash to refer folder in firebase Storage
                    final File downloadFile = new File(folderLocation + "/" + "Picture1" + ".jpg");
                    storageReference.child(STORAGE_PATH_DOWNLOADS +
                             "Picture1.jpg").getFile(downloadFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            if (downloadFile.exists()) {
                                Picasso.get().load(downloadFile).resize(1024, 800).noPlaceholder().onlyScaleDown().centerCrop().into(postImage);
                            } else {
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
```

Comment: For the next few months, use `android:allowLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your `<application>` in the manifest. After that, what you are seeking is no longer supported. Or, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the *user* decide where on the *user's* device your app should be putting the *user's* content.

Comment: What you are suggesting will not work for Android 11 users who newly installs the app.

Comment: Both of my solutions will work for Android 11 users who newly install the app. `android:allowLegacyExternalStorage="true"` will only work until your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 30, and you will be forced into doing that within months, perhaps weeks. So, of the two, I recommend `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, which has been around for ~7 years.